# Plotting legend and getting: Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : plot.new has not been called yet

Tags: r, plot, time-series, rstudio, legend

I've created multiple time series in rStudio. And I am attempting to plot it using `ts.plot()`. The plot works fine but adding a legend causes issues and gives :

> Error in strwidth(legend, units = "user", cex = cex, font = text.font) : plot.new has not been called yet.

I have tried running all the code at once and adjusting the parameters.

```
ts.plot(nltnr.ts, peitnr.ts, nstnr.ts, nbtnr.ts, qbtnr.ts, ontnr.ts, mbtnr.ts, sktnr.ts, abtnr.ts, bctnr.ts, yktnr.ts, nttnr.ts, nvtnr.ts,
        gpars = list(
        ylab = "Amount in millions",
        col=1:12,
        legend("bottom", legend = 1:12)
        ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ts.plot(nltnr.ts, peitnr.ts, nstnr.ts, nbtnr.ts, qbtnr.ts, ontnr.ts, mbtnr.ts, sktnr.ts, abtnr.ts, bctnr.ts, yktnr.ts, nttnr.ts, nvtnr.ts,
        gpars = list(
        ylab = "Amount in millions",
        col=1:12))
        legend("bottom", legend = 1:12)
```

Try running the legend() command after doing your plot, and not while running your plot.

Comment: Running the legend command on it's own is what is giving me this error!